# Rigidbody2D goes through walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add the ability for the player to pick up boxes and move them around, but when the player picks up a box and touches a wall, it starts to twitch and go through it.

Please tell me how this can be fixed. I'm at a dead end.

Here is a video displaying my problem: https://youtu.be/TGt73ASBYpQ

Some code:

```
//The point at which an box is attracted    
attractedTo = player.transform.position + (player.lookDirection * player.itemHoldDistance);
//Attraction
transform.position += attractedTo - transform.position;
```

P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, `transform.position` creates an absolute component and changing it creates point-to-point displacement. transform never considers physics and colliders. Use `rigidbody` to solve the problem.

```cs
private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
public void Start() => rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

```cs
rigidbody.MovePosition(attractedTo);
```

If the problem persists, you must create a condition not to be on the wall.

```cs
public LayerMask wallLayer; // define layer field

if (boxCollider.IsTouchingLayers(wallLayer.value)) return; // =
```

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the position of the held object use the rigidbody functions like AddForce instead.

Comment: I thought about this, but I need the box to follow the mouse clearly. How can this be done with addforce?

Comment: Try setting the object drag and angular drag to something high while you are holding it and add force towards the point where you want it to be.

Comment: this does not fit. The box moves too smoothly and constantly tries to cut its way to a point through the player, thereby pushing him to the side.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).